# Como juntar listas em c#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, visual-studio-2013, lista

Tenho duas classes:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int ProCodigo { get; set; }

    public string ProNome { get; set; }

    public int DepCodigo { get; set; }
    public virtual Departamento Departamento { get; set; }

}

public class Departamento
{
    public int DepCodigo { get; set; }

    public string DepNome { get; set; }
}
```

Se eu fizer duas listas: uma de produtos (onde o objeto de departamento dentro do produto está vazio) e outra de departamentos, é possível relacioná-las? Por exemplo, criar outra lista de produtos com os objetos de departamento dentro dos produto?

Obrigado!

Comment: vc disse q recebe a lista como json, tem um exemplo do json e qual biblioteca vc usa pra deserializar? Talvez no momento de fazer isso você já consiga montar a lista com os devidos relacionamentos de forma mais eficiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim:

```
foreach (var produto in listaProdutos)
{
    produto.Departamento = listaDepartamentos.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepCodigo == produto.DepCodigo);
}
```

Suponho `listaProdutos` a lista de produtos e `listaDepartamentos` a lista de departamentos. Itero a lista de produtos. Para cada produto, procuro um departamento com o código do departamento do produto.

`FirstOrDefault` devolve o departamento se encontrar o departamento ou `null` em caso contrário.

Comment: Entendi, é que eu recebo essa lista de produto por Json dai ele não adiciona os departamentos aos produtos. Então esse é o único jeito?

Comment: Não diria o único jeito. Diria o jeito certo.

Answer (score -1):

Veja se isso te resolve:

```
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>();
      lista1.Add(1);
      lista1.Add(5);

      List<int> lista2 = new List<int>();
      lista2.Add(6);
      lista2.Add(9);
      lista2.Add(1);

      List<int> lista3 = new List<int>();

      foreach (int i in lista1.Where(c => lista2.Contains(c)))
      {
        lista3.Add(i);
      }
```